# Can't access to the Appcelerator Cloud Services from C#

Tags: c#, rest, cloud, appcelerator

I'm trying to connect to the ACS from an application made in C#, first I tried to login but I couldn't connect, instead I got this error message: `The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable`. This is my code:

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String url = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/login.json?key=esfob3KF1R2zBRh8vroMQCCMlQCP44xx&login=prueba123@mail.com&password=" + txtClave.Text;

        WebRequest wrGetUrl = WebRequest.Create(url);

        Stream objStream = wrGetUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(); //I get the error in this line
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objStream);

        String line = reader.ReadToEnd();

        MessageBox.Show(line);
    }
```

I can make queries but for those I don't require to login, in the application I'm working I also have to create `Photos` and `Custom Objects`. Can somebody help me in this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/users/login), you need to use `POST` method for that call:

```
wrGetUrl.Method = "POST";
```